# Young's Double Slit Experiment and particle nature

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-electrodynamics, double-slit-experiment, wave-particle-duality

What happens if we really dim down the light in young's double slit experiment?
How does the result relates to particle nature of light?

Comment: please read my answer here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/388026/is-the-double-slit-experiment-performed-measuring-single-photons/388050#388050 for links to an experiment one photon at a time. It shows both the particle nature and the classical wave nature in the accumulation

Comment: @annav I always enjoy the one photon at a time video you post but earlier today I asked a question and I was wondering if anyone has ever done a video of a diffraction grading one photon at a time experiment. I would be very interested.

Comment: @BillAlsept No, I am sorry. There is the link of the lectures with plots in the comments of your question, which I also found. In any case I prefer this photo recorded experiment I usually post., that can be assimilated fast.

Comment: @annav I wonder why it’s never been done. It seems like it would be just as easy to accomplish as the double slit but it would be more interesting.

Comment: The experiment has been done as seen here, except total plots are shown, they say it is with single photons at a time https://www3.nd.edu/~nsl/Lectures/Laboratory/03_Opt_Diff_&_Interference.pdf , they have not gone to the trouble to make a video.