# Does Intensity actually effect the number of photons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Does Intensity actually effect the number of photons?This question I ask because that's what I knew until I referred to the book by Dirac on quantum mechanics which says:" the wave function gives information about the probability of one Photon being in a particular place and not the probable  number of photons in that place".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does Intensity actually effect the number of photons?

Intensity is defined in classical electromagnetic field, including light.

Photons obey quantum mechanics as quantum mechanical [elementary particles.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle)

Photons carry the energy $h*ν$ where $ν$  is the frequency of the classical beam which is built up by very many photons and $h$ the [Planck constant.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant)

In quantum mechanics the wavefunction  models the probability of finding a single  photon at (x,y,z,t), so there is no problem with Dirac's statement.One needs many measurements of photons with the same condition to find this.

> " the wave function gives information about the probability of one Photon being in a particular place and not the probable number of photons in that place".

To find the number of photons in a  monochromatic pulse of classical light, one needs to know the energy in the pulse and divide it by the energy of the individual photon to find the number of photons.

[See this answer of mine t](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/388026/is-the-double-slit-experiment-performed-measuring-single-photons/388050#388050)o get an intuition of how photons build up the classical wave of light.

Comment: So does that mean the classical wave builder up by photons is different from the wave function associated with it?

Comment: ofcourse, they are solutions of different  equations, the classical ,classical maxwell, the quantum quantized maxwell.